# Send an Email when the network is available

Tags: android, email, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android application for scheduling an email to be sent at specified time.
Now I succeeded by setting a broadcast receiver and using a pending intent.
Now the problem is: suppose that at the scheduled network or internet connection is not available, how can I achieve that action?
I can register a broadcast receiver for the internet connection but i don't know how to use it then.
Help me out.

whenever the user sets time I am calling this setAlarm method()

```
   private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

         email = editTextEmail.getText().toString();
         subject = editTextSubject.getText().toString();
         message = editTextMessage.getText().toString();
        //
        Toast.makeText(AlarmActivity.this, "Mail Scheduled at " + targetCal.getTime(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
        int uniqueValue = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        intent.putExtra("email", email);
        intent.putExtra("sub", subject);
        intent.putExtra("msg", message);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getApplicationContext(), uniqueValue, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);
        AlarmActivity.this.finish();

    }
```

At onReceive method i will call send email method()

```
  public static void sendMail(Context c,String em, String sub,String msg){
    try {

        sender.sendMail(sub, msg, un, em);
        Toast.makeText(c, "Mail Being Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       no.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL; 
        nf.notify(Notify,no);

  } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(c,
                      "There are problem with sending mail. ",
                      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mgr.notify(fail, note);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`

`android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED`

Whenever the network status changes i.e if it connects or disconnects, you will get these two broadcasts. You can receive these broadcasts and can send the email.

For more info you can refer this tutorial

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

Comment: I referred the above link and got an idea for my project thanks @Abhishek. do i check every time for the internet connectivity broadcast receiver when ever the mail is scheduled? because I am passing mail id, subject, and message with my pending intent , when the receiver notified i used those values to send mail. Why I am using this is, the user can schedule multiple mails to the multiple recipients.

Comment: Yes..After receiving the broadcast check if the internet is connected and then send the mail...because you will get the broadcast when the network is disconnected too

Answer (score 1):

You can send email by directly opening the "Send Email" dialog:

```
Intent emailActivity = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email });
            emailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "SubjectName");
            emailActivity.setType("message/rfc822");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailActivity,
                    "Select your Email Provider :"));
```

If you have any confusion, see [this demo](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/email/android-how-to-send-email/).

If you want to check the Internet connection, it's very easy:

```
public class Internetconnection 
{
     public static boolean CheckNetConnectivity(Context mContext) 
     {
        ConnectivityManager connec = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED
                || connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
            return true;

        return false;

    }
}
```

Comment: suppose user wants to send email immediately means then we can use this intent. I am creating mail scheduler where user can set some time to be sent email. When ever the time comes, mail will be sent automatically with some notification as mail sent.

Comment: create email chooser will ask user to choose the email client. But that is not suitable for my project. I can send using javax.mail library to send email at background.

Comment: Ok Thn Its Very Easy I Update My Answer I Send Asyntask Code The help of this Your Internet Connection Chek And Also U can Send Your Mail Immediatly. You Have To call "new SetDataOfWebService().execute();" This In Your scheduler thn its wrk prprly

Comment: thats fine @ishu. but I used simply a broadcast receiver when ever mail is scheduled. After receiving i just called send mail method to send. shall i paste my code which I used to send mail then you can guide me according to that.

Comment: sorry i cant paste here becuase character is limited.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43832/discussion-between-sathish-and-ishu)

Answer (score 1):

> use this code

```
Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { email address whom you want to send});
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, new String[]{ to});
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, new String[]{to});
   email.setData(Uri.parse( email address whom you want to send)); 
   email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Regards");
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailActivity,
                        "Select your Email Provider :"));
```